# How can I disable the checkbox and update the database with php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

How can I disable the checkbox and update the db using php? I mean, if the value is 1 the checkbox is checked and updated in the db, but if I unchecked the checkbox i want that in my db to be updated with 0.

```
$watered = $row['water'];
$i =$watered;
$check = $i == 1 ? 'checked' : '';


<input type="checkbox"  name="check" value = "$watered" <?php echo $check;?> OnClick="doAction(<?php echo $id;?>);" > </td>
```

the function doAction who doesn't matter and the file where is gone:

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = mysql_query("update plants set watered = 1 where id = $id ");
        if ($query){
            echo "you have watered the plants.";
        }else {
            echo "you cannot watered the plants";
        }
    }else{
        echo "vvvvvvvvv";
}
```

Comment: I tried to echo  $_GET['check'] but didn't print anything

Comment: You can do get checkbox value, so It will return all selected checkbox so update it to database and then Select all value which is not equal to your selected checkbox , So you got all unselected checkbox, Now set value 0 for that all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$check = $row['water'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '';

<input type="checkbox"  name="check" value = "<?php echo  $row['water']; ?>" <?php echo $check;?> OnClick="doAction(<?php echo $id;?>);" > </td>
```

And

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); //some security...
  $check = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['check']); //some security...
        $query = mysql_query("update plants set watered = ".$check." where id = ".$id);
        if ($query){
            echo "you have watered the plants.";
        }else {
            echo "you cannot watered the plants";
        }
    }else{
        echo "vvvvvvvvv";
}
```

Sorry, it's really hard to understand you code.... Please do everything with PDO or mysqli, mysql_* functions are **deprecated**. Is it working?

Comment: not really. i don't get it. why did you change the argument of the doAction function from $id with $row[...]?

Comment: sorry, I have seen in your code that $i==$watered==$row['water'] and I read that $id as $i. Fixed. Sorry about that :)